# Is "rallet" a word in this crossword exercise?

Tags: meaning

[image]
I have this puzzle where the highlighted boxes need to be a word, and the clues are:

1. You need this for surfing on the sea or snow
2. You kick the ball to score this
3. Hockey and football are played on this
4. You run races on this
5. This protects your head.
6. This is a word for running and jumping

Comment: I have the correct answer to the puzzle, but leave it other readers as an exercise. I suspect, from the answer that Jasper has worked it out also! So, no, rallet isn't a word, nor is it the word you are looking for!

Comment: Whats the word 

Comment: Wasn't this asked yesterday?

Comment: This does not look like a crossword puzzle. Why does it matter whether those letters spell *rallet* or not?

Comment: I'm not sure if there is another word for it, but this is a type of simple "crossword" used in educational (or sometimes newspaper) puzzles.  If you look, the "rallet" column is shaded, indicating it is special.  There's probably an additional clue or instruction not included in the posted question regarding that column.

Answer (score 3):

No, I have never heard of a "rallet".  It is close to the words "ballet" and "mallet", but your answer to question 1 seems correct.

I know that there is another valid answer to question 4.  Tofystedeth pointed out that there is another valid answer to question 3.  Question 3 should be "Field hockey and Premier League Football are played on this."  And I suspect that "You hold this when you play tennis or badminton" is a good clue for the highlighted word.

Comment: I can think of another possible answer to 3 that would fit.  The current answer is what I would guess being a US English speaker, but a British English speaker would use a different word that would combine with the alternate answer to 4 to make a real word.

Comment: @Tofystedeth is it "pitch"?  Although to me that only works for cricket, not hockey or football.

Comment: @Andrew Yeah, that's what I was going for.  It works for non American football (i.e, soccer) so I assume it should work for other sports played on fields.  I was just being coy because I didn't want to directly provide the answer.  There might other answers but that's by far the best I could come up with to get a 'c' in the correct position.

Comment: @Tofystedeth  I was stumped until you said it was a *British* expression.  :)

Comment: @tofystedeth . . .but a British English speaker might well prefer an alternative spelling for said item, which, er, doesn't fit at all.

Answer (score 1):

This question was asked yesterday and we suggested that we don't do homework! However, this is not a crossword, or all the down words would have to be words and be numbered. So, imo, the question is moot. Without down clues this is simply a word list read left to right. ON EDIT: It has been pointed out to me that I am wrong about this.

The teacher maybe flexible in accepting answers as well. Track or trail. Athletics or exercises. Field or grass -- they all work.

Comment: This is a form of crossword.  It's not directly stated in the question, but the letters in the shaded column are meant to form a word related to the theme established in the rest of the puzzle.  It's a common exercise in English classes.

Comment: @Tofystedeth I have never seen his and thought the OP had shaded the line. Thank you. I taught for over 30 years, but not English as an additional language. You taught me something new!

Comment: We don't do people's homework for them, but we do answer questions about tests and homework if our answers can help someone understand the topic (instead of just get a correct answer to fill in a blank). See [Policy on homework questions](http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/q/1151/) for more information.